# Return the ID of an inserted row which uses subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Yet another sql (oracle) question.

I'm trying to return the ID of an inserted row, but there's a catch.  The insert uses a subquery.

```
create or replace procedure NEW_FORECAST_PROFILE (CA_ID IN NUMBER, FP_ID OUT NUMBER)

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO FORECAST_PROFILE(
    NAME,
    COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID
  )

  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON-DD-yyyy HH:MM AM') AS NAME,
    COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID
  FROM MASTER_DEFAULTS
  WHERE COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID = CA_ID

  RETURNING FORECAST_PROFILE_ID INTO FP_ID;

END;
```

What I'm trying to do:

1) Find a single row in one table and copy it to another table.

2) Return the new row's ID (FORECAST_PROFILE_ID), which was auto-incremented by a trigger/sequence combo.

I'm open to ideas.  This doesn't work because I'm guessing the sql parser expects there to be multiple IDs returning.

I found something close but I need to convert to oracle syntax:

```
DECLARE @inserted_ids TABLE ([id] INT);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[some_table] ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5],[col6])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] INTO @inserted_ids
VALUES (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6)
```

** Update **
One (bad) way to solve the problem is to get the current value of the sequence used to generate the column.  However, I would think this would run into problems if multiple users were updating the table.

```
FP_ID := FORECAST_PROFILES_SEQ.CURRVAL;
```

Comment: Use `returning FORECAST_PROFILE_ID bulk collect into your_nt`, then read `your_nt(1)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - that's nice, I didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your select *might* return multiple rows. Maybe not now, but who knows who is going to butcher your schema in the future. Oracle doesn't bother to check whether `company_account_id` has a unique constraint and that the constraint is valid and enabled.

I would re-organise the statement as follows:

```
FOR r_profile IN (
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON-DD-yyyy HH:MM AM') AS NAME,
        COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID
    FROM MASTER_DEFAULTS
    WHERE COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID = CA_ID
)
LOOP

  INSERT INTO FORECAST_PROFILE (
      NAME,
      COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID
  ) VALUES (
      r_profile.NAME,
      r_profile.COMPANY_ACCOUNT_ID
  ) RETURNING
      FORECAST_PROFILE_ID INTO L_FP_ID
  ;
END;

FP_ID := L_FP_ID;
```

You'd just need to declare your `L_FP_ID` local variable, although you could probably skip that altogether and use `FP_ID`. The downside is that if there were ever changes to the system such that the query DOES return more than one row, you'll only return the last id.

Comment: I skipped the L_FP_ID and went directly to FP_ID.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks! :)